# Read bits, write bits data to arbitrary position in char array

Tags: c++, bitwise

I created functions to read bit data from arbitrary bit position of a `char` array to `long long int`, and I also created a function to write data to a `char` array from `vector bool`.

However, I do not really like my implementation since I think it has a burdensome implementation when reading and writing bits. Can anyone see my implementation and enlighten me on a better implementation?

Here is my implementation to write bit data from `vector<bool> bitdataForModification`.

- `unsigned char*& str` is the original `char` array.
- `int startBitLocation` is an arbitrary bit position to read from.
- `int sizeToModify` is the size in bits for modification.

```
void setBitDataToBitPosition(unsigned char*& str, int startBitLocation, int sizeToModify, std::vector<bool>& bitdataForModification){
    int endBitLocation = startBitLocation + sizeToModify-1;
    int sizeChar = (endBitLocation - startBitLocation)/8;

    //Save leftover data    
    int startCharPosition = startBitLocation/8;
    int startLeftOverBits = startBitLocation%8;

    //endPosition
    int endCharPosition = endBitLocation/8;
    int endLeftOverBits = 7-(endBitLocation%8);

    unsigned char tempChar = str[startCharPosition];
    unsigned char tempLastChar = str[endCharPosition]; // store last char

    int posBitdata = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < startLeftOverBits; i++){
        str[startCharPosition] <<= 1;
        str[startCharPosition] = (str[startCharPosition] | ((tempChar >> (7-i)) & 0x1));
    }

    for(int i = startCharPosition*8 + startLeftOverBits ; i <= endBitLocation ; i++){
        str[i/8] <<= 1;
        if(posBitdata <= endBitLocation){
            str[i/8] = (str[i/8] | ((bitdataForModification[posBitdata]) & 0x1));
            posBitdata++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < endLeftOverBits ; i++){
        str[endCharPosition] <<= 1;
        str[endCharPosition] = (str[endCharPosition] | ((tempChar >> i) & 0x1));
    }

}
```

I do not like this function because it copies from the original `char[]` to a temp `char[]` and copies back the bits I need.

Following is my read function I implemented. It reads from a `char` array and copies the data to `long long int data`.

```
void getBitDataFromBitPosition(unsigned char* str, int startBitLocation, int sizeToRead, unsigned long long* data){
    int endBitLocation = startBitLocation + sizeToRead;
    int sizeChar = (endBitLocation - startBitLocation)/8;

    int startCharPosition = startBitLocation/8;
    int endCharPosition = endBitLocation/8 +1;

    vector<bool> bitData;

    int bitCnt = 0;
    for(int i = startCharPosition; i < endCharPosition; i++){
        unsigned char tempChar = str[i];

        for(int j = 7 ; j >= 0 ; j--){
            int curLoc = ((i*8)+(bitCnt%8));
            if(curLoc >= startBitLocation){
                if(curLoc < endBitLocation){

                    bool temp = ((str[i] >> j) & 0x1);
                    bitData.push_back(temp);
                }
            }
            bitCnt++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = bitData.size() -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
        *data <<= 1;
        *data = (*data | bitData[bitData.size()-i-1]);      
    }
}
```

I think it is a burden to copy to a `bool vector` and copy back to `long long int`. Can anyone provide a better solution for me?